# editing the php variable

Tags: php, string, variables, edit

im getting the logging times of my site, written to a textfile from the below code.

```
$message1 = "{\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0#2014-09-12 04:33:38am\";}";
    $timearray = explode('#', $message1, 2);
    $time = strval($timearray[1]);
    $file = "testtxt.txt";
    $write = ($time."\n");
    file_put_contents($file, $write, FILE_APPEND);
```

but the problem is i get the result as follows

```
2014-09-12 04:33:38am";}
```

can anybody hellp me on getting rid of

```
":}
```

in the time result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working solution for you:

```
$time      = str_replace('";}', '', strval($timearray[1]));
```

Tested it already, works.

Comment: I would actually suggesst using regular expressions / exploding for that purpose. If your string structure changes, then your script would stop working. But if you fetched this via regular expressions, it would alyways fetch you the date.

Answer (score 1):

cause explode index will give you result `2014-09-12 04:33:38am\";}` so need to remove it to get only time try `str_replace()`

```
$time = strval($timearray[1]);
$time = str_replace('":}','',$time);
```

or in one line

```
$write = (str_replace('":}','',$time)."\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with fallowing code, i hope this will help u out.

$message1 = "{\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0#2014-09-12 04:33:38am\";}";
    $timearray = explode('#', $message1, 2);
    $time1 = strval($timearray[1]);
    $timearray1 = explode('"',$time1, 2);
    $time=strval($timearray1[1]);
    $file = "testtxt.txt";
    $write = ($time."\n");
    file_put_contents($file, $write, FILE_APPEND);